# Not able to execute sudo command on "Send files or execute commands over SSH"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to execute sudo command over SSH. Sharing the Jenkins set up below.

[image]

These are my execute commands:

```
cd ~/univu_jenkins/tc-console/$BUILD_TIMESTAMP
chmod -R 777 ~/univu_jenkins/tc-console/$BUILD_TIMESTAMP
sudo -r cp -r ~/univu_jenkins/tc-console/$BUILD_TIMESTAMP/* /var/www/tcserver/test"
sudo nginx -s reload
```

I have checked  "Exec in pty". The error I am getting is:

[image]

I have added jenkins user in my Jenkins server sudoers location i.e.

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Try running `whoami` before your `sudo` commands and make sure that the user is actually `jenkins`.

Comment: thank you ,my user is not jenkins .Its resolved after adding my user in the target machine .